# Backward alternative solution for ChronoUnit.Days.between()

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-time, date-difference

I need an alternative solution for ChronoUnit.Days.between() that works for Android version prior to API 26.

Please!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ThreeTen Android Backport`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The `ChronoUnit` enum that you are referring to is part of java.time (the modern Java date and time API). This has been backported, and the backport further adapted for Android. So you may in most cases keep the code you wrote for API level 26 and only modify your imports to import `org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit`, etc.

Comment: Normally I would not upbvote a link only answer, but this one is to the point and does fully answer the question. The question isn’t specific enough to warrant more depth in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TimeUnit` instead (since Java 5):

```java
long diffEpochMillis = Math.abs(lastDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());
long diffDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Does it take Leap-year and DAYLIGHT SAVING into account?

Comment: I would say that it does not take timezone information into consideration. It just calculates the number of milliseconds since the epoch and converts that amount into days. Is it a requirement to consider leap years, gap days and other timezone-specific information?

Comment: Yes, It does require leap years